# Pause Shader that uses CC_TIME in cocos2d-x

Tags: shader, cocos2d-x

I am using a shader that is using cocos2d-x's variable CC_Time[1].
I am wondering how to tell cocos2d-x not to update anymore the CC_Time value, when I want to pause my game.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found no solution to do this via cocos2d-x's director but i passed a boolean variable (uniform) to my shader that indicates to pause its main loop. Works fine.